# REACT-NATIVE Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, powershell

I'm trying to emulate the command `npx react-native init AwesomeProject`, in an Android Studio app, but I'm getting this error.

[image: The error]

I tried repairing the archives with commands, and updating the SDK archives too.

Comment: The bottom of errors indicates the project did not compile.  Post lines of code shown in the error messages.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).